# Why Angular 9? Is there a significant change from the previous version?

Tags: angular, version, angular9

My company has to choose version of angular for a new project uses typeScript.
What are the differences between previous version and version 9?

Answer (score 1):

```
Changes are mostly related to the bug/feature & re-introduce more things.<br>

1. some imports for rxjs have been changed like below one <br><br>
instead of -<br>
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';<br>
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';<br>
Use a single import -<br>
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';<br>

2. .angular-cli.json now changed to angular.json<br><br>
path reference has been for the bootstrap import has changed now <br>
earlier it was used to be <br><br>
"styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          ],<br><br>
Now,
"styles": [
            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          ],

There are lot more changes that are done. For details you can refer the below link for getting more info.<br>
https://www.code-sample.com/2017/11/angular-5-vs-angular-6-new-features.html
```